# __str__ returned non-string (type Leads)

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error and I am not able to figure it out:

> TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type Leads)

```
class Leads(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=0)
    contact_person_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=0 ,blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey("packsapp.Employee", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='createdby')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Pfep(models.Model):

    client = models.ForeignKey(Leads, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vendor_owner')
    receiver = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=0 ,blank=True, null=True)
    receiver_location = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=0 ,blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.client

class PPboxSol(models.Model):

    box_length = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    box_breadth = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    box_height = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    pfep = models.ForeignKey(Pfep, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='pfep_box_sol')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey("packsapp.Employee", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ppbox_createdby')
```

Views.py

```
class PpboxsolFormView(CreateView):
    model = PPboxSol
    form_class = Ppboxsolform
    template_name = 'pfep/PpboxsolForm.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['pfep'] = Pfep.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return initial

    def form_valid (self, form):
        if self.request.user.employee.employee_role == 'admin':
            product = form.save(commit=False)
            product.created_by = Employee.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id)[0]
            product.save()
            messages.success(self.request, 'The PP Box Solution was created with success!')
            return redirect('emp:ppbox_table')
        else:
            messages.success(self.request, "You don't have permission to create Solution!")
            return redirect('emp:ppbox_table')

        return redirect('emp:pfep_table')
```

Urls.py

```
     path('ppboxsol/add/<int:pk>/', PpboxsolFormView.as_view(), name='ppbox_form'),
```

Do I need to add `def __str__(self):` to model `PPboxSol` as well ?

Edit:

I have added the `Leads` model as well, but that also returns a str

Comment: Can You Please Show Your Leads Model

Comment: a `models.ForeignKey` is not a string. Maybe cast it to string first?

Comment: It means exactly what it says. `TypeError` means there is an error because something is the wrong type. It tells you that the `__str__` method returned something which was not a string. So that thing that was returned, is the thing that is the wrong type. You need to return a string instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a lead field name you want to show for example user model if we want to show username so we need to use `user.username`

Try This:

```
class Pfep(models.Model):

    client = models.ForeignKey(Leads, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vendor_owner')
    receiver = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=0 ,blank=True, null=True)
    receiver_location = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=0 ,blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.client.name)#name for example
```

Comment: I understood where the problem was.. thanks to you `def __str__(self):
        return self.client` was returning integers and i was trying to pass it on as str